# Size of image not fitting into storyboard view for compact w regular h size class

Tags: swift, xcode7

I've added a bunch of images to my program and have set them in the appropriate spots 1x, 2x etc. in the image assets file (and have also set them for their respective sizes) but when I try to drag the image directly from the media library onto my view (for the compact width and regular height size class - iPhone size in portrait), the image that is going in is the iPad's version and so it doesn't fit. I first added an image view to test this, and while this gets the image fitting the image view, it is still the same iPad version that is getting selected.

The media library just shows one image and then the number 6 beside it to show the different ones, but I can't seem to be able to select the specific image I want from here. Is there an easy way to resolve this?

It seems to be adding the iPad version into my iPhone compact w regular h view.

This is the set of images I have added:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about this wrong. Distinguish resolution from size.

- Your job is to set the *size* of the *image view* that will hold this image.
- The runtime will *automatically* pick the version of the image that is correct for the current device's screen *resolution*.